# I Want to Disable Delete Button Base On auth()->user()->id (LARAVEL 8)

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-statements

I have make Users Index where on that table displaying all user data except Password and at the last field i put action for Delete user. The problem is i want to disable delete button only for the user who login at that time. But what i have done is all user delete button disable, please help me how to solve this. i have trying to find tutoril but didn't  find yet. Below my condition code:

```
@if (auth()->user()->id)
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger
    btn-xs" disabled><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>Delete</button>
@else
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger
    btn-xs"><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>Delete</button>
@endif
```

In UserController to display all user data i use this code:

```
public function index(){
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.users.index', ['users'=> $users]);
}
```

in index.blade i aplly this code to display all data:

```
<table id="dataTableBasic" class="table" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ __('Username') }}</th>
        <th>{{ __('Name') }}</th>
        <th>{{ __('Email') }}</th>
        <th>{{ __('Role') }}</th>
        <th>{{ __('Posts') }}</th>
        <th>{{ __('Action') }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{route('user.profile.show', $user->id)}}" class="text-inherit link-primary">{{$user->username}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{{$user->email}}" class="text-inherit link-primary">{{$user->email}}</a></td>
        <td>Administrator</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="text-inherit">100</a></td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{route('users.destroy',$user->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                @if (auth()->user()->id)
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs" disabled><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>{{ __('Hapus') }}</button>
                @else
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs"><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>{{ __('Hapus') }}</button>
                @endif
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You have to decide on what basis you want to disable delete button. Like current logged in user match to user id who comes in loop

Comment: it's solved mate. thank u.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if the `$user->id` is the same as the authenticated user's id:

```
@if(auth()->id() === $user->id)
```

Also, since the only different between the buttons in the `disabled` attribute, you could do:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dangerbtn-xs"
        @if($user->id === auth()->id()) disabled @endif>
    <i class="fe fe-trash"></i>
    Delete
</button>
```

Comment: OMG it's worked. thank u so much.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <td>
        <form action="{{route('users.destroy',$user->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            @if (auth()->id())
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs" disabled><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>Delete</button>
            @else
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs"><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>Delete</button>
            @endif
        </form>
    </td>
```

Comment: I have solved, i just replace this code: `@if (auth()->user()->id) <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs" disabled><i class="fe fe-trash"></i>Delete</button> @else <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs"><i class="fe fe-trash" </i>Delete</button> @endif`  With this code: `<button class="btn btn-outline-dangerbtn-xs" @if($user->id === auth()->id()) disabled @endif><i class="fe fe-trash"></i> Delete</button>` that i got from brother @Rwd.